# WSO2 API Manager 2.1 Analytics - Fails to Start up while connecting to Oracle DB

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am deploying WSO2 API Manager 2.1 and Analytics using the Pattern as specified - https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/tree/master/docker-compose/pattern-3

Here in all the components - nginx, Publisher, Store, Traffic Manager, Gateway Worker, Gateway Manager, Key Manager and Analytics are deployed as separate docker containers.
When I started these containers, it worked fine and by default it was using the mysql server for storing all the data.

But as per our requirement, we had to use the Oracle DB and hence, we created a user in there with all the required permissions and then run the oracle scripts and finally started all the containers one by one.
In addition for Analytics, we created two separate users for two data sources - WSO2_ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE_DB and WSO2_ANALYTICS_PROCESSED_DATA_STORE_DB (Didnt run any scripts for these).

And now we have a problem with the Analytics COntainer not able to start and throwing the error -

[2017-07-11 12:53:54,017]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2017-07-11 12:53:54,017]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating System : Linux 4.8.0-53-generic, amd64
[2017-07-11 12:53:54,017]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home        : /mnt/jdk-7u80/jre
[2017-07-11 12:53:54,017]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Version     : 1.7.0_80
[2017-07-11 12:53:54,017]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.80-b11,Oracle Corporation
[2017-07-11 12:53:54,018]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home      : /mnt/186.12.12.12/wso2am-analytics-2.1.0
[2017-07-11 12:53:54,018]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir    : /mnt/186.12.12.12/wso2am-analytics-2.1.0/tmp
[2017-07-11 12:53:54,018]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User             : root, en-US, GMT

[2017-07-11 12:54:34,104]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater} -  Permission cache updated for tenant -1234
[2017-07-11 12:54:34,235]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.http.HttpsTransportListener} -  HTTPS port       : 9444
[2017-07-11 12:54:34,235]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.http.HttpTransportListener} -  HTTP port        : 9764

[2017-07-11 12:54:36,547]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer} -  Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/analytics].File[/mnt/186.12.12.12/wso2am-analytics-2.1.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/analytics.war]
[2017-07-11 12:54:36,593]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer} -  Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/inputwebsocket].File[/mnt/186.12.12.12/wso2am-analytics-2.1.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/inputwebsocket.war]
[2017-07-11 12:54:36,622]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer} -  Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/outputwebsocket].File[/mnt/186.12.12.12/wso2am-analytics-2.1.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/outputwebsocket.war]
[
[2017-07-11 12:54:43,116]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.EventProcessorDeployer} -  Execution plan deployment held back and in inactive state : APIMAnalytics-RequestSummarizer-RequestSummarizer-realtime1.siddhiql, Dependency validation exception: Stream org.wso2.apimgt.statistics.requestsPerMinPerKeyStream:1.0.0 does not exist
[2017-07-11 12:54:43,186]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.EventProcessorDeployer} -  Execution plan deployment held back and in inactive state : APIMAnalytics-UnusualIPAccessTemplate-UnusualIPAccessAlert-realtime1.siddhiql, Dependency validation exception: Stream org.wso2.apimgt.statistics.perMinuteRequest:1.0.0 does not exist
[2017-07-11 12:54:43,218]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.ThriftDataReceiver} -  Thrift Server started at 0.0.0.0
[2017-07-11 12:54:43,246]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.ThriftDataReceiver} -  Thrift SSL port : 7712
[2017-07-11 12:54:43,253]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.ThriftDataReceiver} -  Thrift port : 7612
[2017-07-11 12:54:43,277]  INFO {org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool} -  Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
[2017-07-11 12:54:43,355]  INFO {org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool} -  Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
[2017-07-11 12:54:43,408]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.service.impl.TaskServiceImpl} -  Task service starting in STANDALONE mode...
[2017-07-11 12:54:44,030] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.AnalyticsDataServiceComponent} -  Error in activating analytics data service: null
java.lang.RuntimeException
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms.RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore$RDBMSResultSetIterator.next(RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore.java:881)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms.RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore$RDBMSResultSetIterator.hasNext(RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore.java:843)
        at org.apache.commons.collections.IteratorUtils.toList(IteratorUtils.java:848)
        at org.apache.commons.collections.IteratorUtils.toList(IteratorUtils.java:825)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.core.util.GenericUtils.listRecords(GenericUtils.java:284)

```
    [2017-07-11 12:54:55,566]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} -  user admin connected
```

[2017-07-11 12:55:05,564] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker} -  Dropping wrongly formatted event sent for -1234
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: Error when converting loganalyzer:1.0.0 of event bundle with events 1
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:181)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.toEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:90)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker.run(QueueWorker.java:73)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: No StreamDefinition for streamId loganalyzer:1.0.0 present in cache

Can someone please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can someone please let me know on this, it is blocking me from moving ahead for API Manager setup.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055154/wso2-api-manager-2-1-analytics-cannot-be-restarted-when-using-oracle-db.
May be it help you

Comment: Can you please tell me from where did you get the jar file - org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms-1.3.6.jar

Answer (score 0):

You can get the newer version of jar from http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/wso2/carbon/analytics/org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try with this jar file.