# WSO2 API Manager 2.1 Analytics cannot be restarted when using Oracle DB

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

When restarting APIM Analytics the following error appears in log (the first run is ok). We need to truncate ANX___8GEKYOMM_ table for being able to start it again.

TID: [-1234] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.AnalyticsDataServiceComponent} -  Error in activating analytics data service: null {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.AnalyticsDataServiceComponent}
java.lang.RuntimeException
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms.RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore$RDBMSResultSetIterator.next(RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore.java:881)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms.RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore$RDBMSResultSetIterator.hasNext(RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore.java:843)
        at org.apache.commons.collections.IteratorUtils.toList(IteratorUtils.java:848)
        at org.apache.commons.collections.IteratorUtils.toList(IteratorUtils.java:825)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.core.util.GenericUtils.listRecords(GenericUtils.java:284)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.AnalyticsDataServiceImpl.readTenantIds(AnalyticsDataServiceImpl.java:468)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms.RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore$RDBMSResultSetIterator.extractDataFromRS(RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore.java:890)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms.RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore$RDBMSResultSetIterator.next(RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore.java:863)
        ... 124 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it upgrading from org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms-1.3.0.jar to org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms-1.3.6.jar